# Magento 2 - Add CMS Static Block to Checkout Address Form

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, shipping-address

Evening All,

I am looking to add a static CMS block to the Magento 2 Checkout delivery address form. I would like display the CMS block under the phone number field. The old method would have been to pull the template into my new theme and update it but in Magento 2 the Checkout is being rendered by knockoutjs and I am a bit lost.

Any help with what knockout templates or XML layout I need to update to do this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to do this with a module, it can't be done from within the theme.

The idea is to get the CMS block's html and put it into the `checkoutConfig` JS object. We do this by adding a config provider to `Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider`

Here is **{module_dir}/etc/frontend/di.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cms_block_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\CheckoutConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\CheckoutConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <!--ID OF THE CMS BLOCK-->
            <argument name="blockId" xsi:type="string">16</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

This will add our config provider and is also where we pass in the ID of the CMS block you want to display.

Now for the config provider **{module_dir}/Model/CheckoutConfigProvider.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;


use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block;

class CheckoutConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    protected $cmsBlockWidget;

    public function __construct(Block $block, $blockId)
    {
        $this->cmsBlockWidget = $block;
        $block->setData('block_id', $blockId);
        $block->setTemplate('Magento_Cms::widget/static_block/default.phtml');
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'cmsBlockHtml' => $this->cmsBlockWidget->toHtml()
        ];
    }
}
```

This renders the block's html and will make it available to javascript in `window.checkoutConfig.cmsBlockHtml`.

Now we need to add a `uiComponent` to the address form. We do this in **{module_dir}/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="cms-block" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/cms-block</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">125</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Finally we just need to create the knockout template file for this `uiComponent`.
It will be **{module_dir}/view/frontend/web/template/cms-block.html**:

```
<div data-bind="html: window.checkoutConfig.cmsBlockHtml"></div>
```

Comment: Ah Excellent, That worked a treat!

Comment: i did the same but not working for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! I put it into a module (see below)

Comment: I have added it in my checkout_index_index.xml` where i have created some tabs for checkout but it doesn't show there.
Will you Please Help @Aaron

Comment: @Prits Did you get it to work? I followed these steps as well and I am seeing the div appear on the checkout page but it is not populated with the block content. Checking console log, there is no `cmsBlockHtml` in `window.checkoutConfig`

Comment: Yes same is in my case the div is appeared but no data found out there @Chrysippus

Comment: @Prits I found [this blog post](https://www.daanbeverdam.com/blog/adding-a-static-cms-block-to-the-magento-2-checkout/) that outlines the method in detail and works perfectly. The sample code is available [on GitHub here](https://github.com/daanbeverdam/checkout-block-provider).

Comment: It Doesn't work for me as i have successfully add all the files.will you please tell it it works  for you @Chrysippus

Comment: @Prits Yes, it works. But there is a typo in `checkout_index_index.xml` on the blog post. `VendorName/ModuleName/js/view/cms-block` should be `VendorName_ModuleName/js/view/cms-block`

Comment: Yes i have figured that out and changed it but does't work.
Will you please check i have added my code https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318729/how-to-show-static-cms-block-in-magento-2-html-file here if you found out something it helly helped me. @Chrysippus

Comment: Thanks for the link it works and shows the data on checkout page.
But i want to show that on my custom tab added between shipping and payment page.
How would i do that will you help me with this. @Chrysippus

Comment: @Prits I don't know how to do that. Sorry.

Comment: Okay no problem still thanks for the link @Chrysippus

Answer (score 10):

This is what I did to display a CMS block on checkout page under sidebar.
 1. In the templates/onepage.phtml I created a js variable to hold the cms block content like this:

```
<?php $myCmsBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('my_cms_block')->toHtml() ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var my_cms_block = <?php echo json_encode($myCmsBlock)?>;
    </script>
```

2. In the knockout template file (in my case it was web/js/template/sidebar.html), displayed the cms block content from the above js variable like this:

```
<div class="opc-help-cms" data-bind="html:my_cms_block">
    </div>
```

Hope this helps someone!
Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem as clean as Aaron's approach, but probably still working well :-)

Comment: Perfect. This code is working fine when we add a CMS block in a section where you can not add it by XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Aarons answer I put that in our [Mestrona_CommonBlocks Magento 2 Module on GitHub](https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CommonBlocks).