# How to show Content Blocks in HTML File in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, html

I have created a custom tab in Magento 2 in which the html part is shown by HTML file.
**Means its extension is (.html)**.

**I want to show some blocks in that html file how would i do that.**.
Infact i have used php tag and echo something it doesn't work there how to show that data inside php tag?

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not run in HTML files so you cannot directly do this.

A common but not very clean workaround is to add the HTML from the static block to `window.checkoutConfig` using PHP and then render that in your HTML file like so:

```
<div data-bind="html: window.checkoutConfig.yourCmsBlock"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, what should i pass in yourCmsBlock because it doesn't work with block ID will you please help @Ben

Comment: That will be whatever you define it as in your PHP, I'm not a PHP developer so I can't help with that bit sorry. It is explained here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173324/magento-2-add-cms-static-block-to-checkout-address-form and here though - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157126/magento-2-how-to-add-additional-block-on-checkout-page

Comment: Its okk and Thanks for the Links.Will you Please look into this question.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318424/how-to-apply-coupon-code-on-custom-tab-in-magento-2/318432?noredirect=1#comment456614_318432
I have removed the discount coupan from checkout page but how would i add in on my custom tab.@BenCook